# String.indexOf function in C

Tags: c, string

Is there a C library function that will return the index of a character in a string?

So far, all I've found are functions like strstr that will return the found char *, not it's location in the original string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that

> size_t strcspn ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );

is what you want. Here is an example pulled from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcspn.html):

```
/* strcspn example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "fcba73";
  char keys[] = "1234567890";
  int i;
  i = strcspn (str,keys);
  printf ("The first number in str is at position %d.\n",i+1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcspn` is more like `String.IndexOfAny()` - searching for any of the characters in the `keys` array. But yeah, it'll do the trick

Comment: The above comment is very important - doing it as in the example DOES NOT mimic indexOf(), so the original answer is pretty much incorrect.

Comment: This is exactily what you are looking for: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1479401/3395760

Comment: Updated [here](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/?kw=strcspn) link in case anyone wants it ...

Answer (score 39):

`strstr` returns a pointer to the found character, so you could use pointer arithmetic:  (Note: this code not tested for its ability to compile, it's one step away from pseudocode.)

```
char * source = "test string";         /* assume source address is */
                                       /* 0x10 for example */
char * found = strstr( source, "in" ); /* should return 0x18 */
if (found != NULL)                     /* strstr returns NULL if item not found */
{
  int index = found - source;          /* index is 8 */
                                       /* source[8] gets you "i" */
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior if the character is not found. Also you should not use `strstr` (with or without the typo) if `strchr` would suffice.

Comment: @R.. - I fixed the typo and added error checking to the pseudocode.  Also, `strchr` does not work for finding multi-character sequences, does it?

Comment: Indeed, but OP asked for a character not a substring. Of course if you interpret character broadly to include multibyte characters, `strstr` is the right function to use.

Comment: @R.. - Since the OP was talking about a character as in text, not as in the `char` storage name, I gave a solution that has a hope of working for a character like 輪.  You object?

Answer (score 14):

EDIT: strchr is better only for one char. 
Pointer aritmetics says "Hellow!":

```
char *pos = strchr (myString, '#');
int pos = pos ? pos - myString : -1;
```

**Important:** strchr () returns NULL if no string is found

Comment: You might want to rewrite the second line as `int ipos = pos ? pos - myString : -1;` to avoid compiler errors - but otherwise this still works in 2023!

Answer (score 4):

You can use strstr to accomplish what you want. Example:

```
char *a = "Hello World!";
char *b = strstr(a, "World");

int position = b - a;

printf("the offset is %i\n", position);
```

This produces the result:

```
the offset is 6
```

Comment: UB if there is no match (subtraction of pointers not within the same object).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not totally tied to pure C and can use string.h there is strchr()
[See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pure C" but strchr() and string.h have been part of Standard C for 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own :)

Code from a BSD licensed string processing library for C, called [zString](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString)

https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString

```
int zstring_search_chr(char *token,char s){
    if (!token || s=='\0')
        return 0;

    for (;*token; token++)
        if (*token == s)
            return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
s="bvbrburbhlkvp";
int index=strstr(&s,"h")-&s;
```

to find the index of `'h'` in the given garble.

Comment: `strstr` might return `NULL` if string was not found.