# Is there a function in c that will return the index of a char in a char array?

Tags: c, string, function, indexing, char

Is there a function in c that will return the index of a char in a char array?

For example something like:

```
char values[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char find = 'E';

int index = findIndexOf( values, find );
```

Comment: [`strchr()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [String.indexOf function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824/string-indexof-function-in-c)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`strchr` returns the pointer to the first occurrence, so to find the index, just take the offset with the starting pointer. For example:

```
char values[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char find = 'E';

const char *ptr = strchr(values, find);
if(ptr) {
   int index = ptr - values;
   // do something
}
```

Comment: my question, how do I find *indexes* in a char. If I had 2 `E` s in the string?

Comment: You did not tell me what to `#include`

Comment: @turmuka then it will only return the first occurance

Answer (score 9):

There's also `size_t strcspn(const char *str, const char *set)`; it returns the index of the first occurence of the character in `s` that is included in `set`:

```
size_t index = strcspn(values, "E");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int index = strchr(values,find)-values;
```

Note, that if there's no `find` found, then `strchr` returns `NULL`, so index will be negative.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic on `NULL` is undefined behavior. It doesn't have to return any particular value.

Comment: That's true, it doesn't have to, but it does usually :). My point was that one should expect NULL pointer here.

Comment: Just because it appears to work for you, it doesn't mean that's right. Your code may randomly fail when pointer is high enough (I actually checked that, see https://gist.github.com/GlitchMr/8056175 (should be an infinite loop, if this would work correctly)).

Comment: I didn't say it's right. And yes, that's very correct what you point out, but it is only because the behaviour is de facto defined you could do that ;)

Answer (score 3):

Safe `index_of()` function that works even when it finds nothing (returns `-1` in such case).

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
ptrdiff_t index_of(const char *string, char search) {
    const char *moved_string = strchr(string, search);
    /* If not null, return the difference. */
    if (moved_string) {
        return moved_string - string;
    }
    /* Character not found. */
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about strpos?

```
#include <string.h>

int index;
...
index = strpos(values, find);
```

Note that strpos expects a zero-terminated string, which means you should add a '\0' at the end. If you can't do that, you're left with a manual loop and search.

Comment: I don't think that exists in the C standard library, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Personally I have more confidence in the strchr answers, I'd really like one of those be marked as the answer instead. I only found one really old piece of source code using that function, and I don't know how standard it is when I consider it.

Comment: strpos() is not a standard C (or even C++) function.  Quite common in PHP, etc...

Comment: Odd, but I do have a piece of C code that uses it. But as I said, I don't know how standard it is.

Comment: strpos isn't part of the C std lib - but it is probably present on most systems.

Comment: after looking through some other code I have found some c that uses strpos()

Comment: +1 for reminding that we can do the manual loop. Cuz in my case i need something like lfind not the rfind which strchr will return.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strcspn()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) to get the index of a char in a string, or use my lousy implementation:

```
// Returns the index of the first occurrence of a char
int string_indexof(char ch, char *everything) {
    int everythingLength = strlen(everything);
    for (int i = 0; i < everythingLength; i++) {
        if (ch == everything[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strchr](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html#strchr) to get a pointer to the first occurrence and the subtract that (if not null) from the original char* to get the position.