# How can I check if a single char exists in a C string?

Tags: c, string, char

I want to check if a single char is in a C string. The character is the `'|'`
used for pipelines in Linux (Actually, I also want to check for `'<'`, `'>'`, `'>>'`, `'&'`).

In Java I can do this:

```
String.indexOf()
```

But how can I do this in C, without looping through the whole string (a `char*` string)?

Comment: `"|"` is a c string, Anything enclosed in double quotes `"`, `"` is a string irrespective of number of characters it has.Either your Q title is misleading or I mis-understand your Q.

Comment: @Als: Correct, fixed. thanks !

Comment: Note that `'>>'` is not a single character. Here you need a different approach (`strstr`).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you need to search for a character you can use the `strchr` function, like this:

```
char* pPosition = strchr(pText, '|');
```

`pPosition` will be `NULL` if the given character has not been found. For example:

```
puts(strchr("field1|field2", '|'));
```

Will output: "|field2". Note that `strchr` will perform a *forward* search, to search *backward* you can use the `strrchr`. Now imagine (just to provide an example) that you have a string like this: "variable:value|condition". You can extract the *value* field with:

```
char* pValue = strrchr(strchr(pExpression, '|'), ':') + 1;
```

If what you want is the *index* of the character inside the string take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479386/is-there-a-function-in-c-that-will-return-the-index-of-a-char-in-a-char-array) here on SO. You may need something like `IndexOfAny()` too, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824/string-indexof-function-in-c) another post on SO that uses `strnspn` for this.

Instead if you're looking for a string you can use the `strstr` function, like this:

```
char* pPosition = strstr(pText, "text to find");
```

Answer (score 5):

[`strchr`](http://man.openbsd.org/strchr) is your friend.

```
char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

> The `strchr` function locates the first occurrence of `c` (converted to a `char`) in the
>   string pointed to by `s`.
>
> The `strchr` function returns a pointer to the located character, or a null pointer if the
>   character does not occur in the string.

And of course, the function has to walk through the whole string in the worst case (as the Java function probably does).

Comment: In constant strchr, c should be char type. I think mistakenly you typed int. It should be: char *strchr(const char *s, char c);

Comment: @Vibhuti: No, it should not. Please check the link in my answer or - in case you don't trust it -  the ISO C standard, e.g.http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf, page 330.