# Finding line size of each row in a text file

Tags: c

How can you count the number of characters or numbers in each line?  Is there something like a EOF thats more like a End of Line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate through each character in the line and keep incrementing a counter until the end-of-line (`'\n'`) is encountered. Make sure to open the file in text mode (`"r"`) and not binary mode (`"rb"`). Otherwise the stream won't automatically convert different platforms' line ending sequences into `'\n'` characters.

Here is an example:

```
int charcount( FILE *const fin )
{
    int c, count;

    count = 0;
    for( ;; )
    {
        c = fgetc( fin );
        if( c == EOF || c == '\n' )
            break;
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Here's an example program to test the above function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    FILE *fin;

    fin = fopen( "test.txt", "r" );
    if( fin == NULL )
        return 1;

    printf( "Character count: %d.\n", charcount( fin ) );

    fclose( fin );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to go character-by-character to get the index of the new line.  You can use strcspn() to find the index of the '\n'.  (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824/string-indexof-function-in-c)

Comment: strcspn() and strspn() do not read from files. To use them, you would have to read the entire line into a string and then re-iterate through it to find the '\n' character. This is less efficient. Of course, it depends on how MRP is doing his file IO code.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding reading a file line by line, look at [fgets](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html).

```
char *fgets(char *restrict s, int n, FILE *restrict stream);
```

> The fgets() function shall read bytes
>   from stream into the array pointed to
>   by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or a
>    is read and transferred to
>   s, or an end-of-file condition is
>   encountered. The string is then
>   terminated with a null byte.

The only problem here may be if you can't guarantee a maximum line size in your file.  If that is the case, you can iterate over characters until you see a line feed.

Regarding end of line:

Short answer: `\n` is the newline character (also called a line feed).

Long answer, from Wikipedia:

> Systems based on ASCII or a compatible
>   character set use either LF (Line
>   feed, 0x0A, 10 in decimal) or CR
>   (Carriage return, 0x0D, 13 in decimal)
>   individually, or CR followed by LF
>   (CR+LF, 0x0D 0x0A); see below for the
>   historical reason for the CR+LF
>   convention. These characters are based
>   on printer commands: The line feed
>   indicated that one line of paper
>   should feed out of the printer, and a
>   carriage return indicated that the
>   printer carriage should return to the
>   beginning of the current line.

```
* LF:    Multics, Unix and Unix-like systems (GNU/Linux, AIX, Xenix, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, etc.), BeOS, Amiga, RISC OS, and others
* CR+LF: DEC RT-11 and most other early non-Unix, non-IBM OSes, CP/M, MP/M, DOS, OS/2, Microsoft Windows, Symbian OS
* CR:    Commodore 8-bit machines, Apple II family, Mac OS up to version 9 and OS-9
```

But since you are not likely to be working with a representation that uses carriage return only, looking for a line feed should be fine.

Comment: soo you can make a loop until char = \n

Comment: FILE *in;
in = fopen ( "numbers.txt", "r" );

  if ( in != NULL ) 
 {

Do I use a fget until \n ?

Comment: Right, it would be fgetc to get a single character.

Comment: @danben: if the file is open in text mode, the underlying library will take care of representing newlines as `'\n'` only, even on windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you open a file in text mode, i.e., without a `b` in the second argument to `fopen()`, you can read characters one-by-one until you hit a `'\n'` to determine the line size.  The underlying system should take care of translating the end of line terminators to just one character, `'\n'`.  The last line of a text file, on some systems, may not end with a `'\n'`, so that is a special case.

Pseudocode:

```
count := 0
c := next()
while c != EOF and c != '\n'"
    count := count + 1
```

the above will count the number of characters in a given line.  `next()` is a function to return the next character from your file.

Alternatively, you can use `fgets()` with a buffer:

```
char buf[SIZE];
count = 0;
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) != NULL) {
    /* see if the string represented by buf has a '\n' in it,
       if yes, add the index of that '\n' to count, and that's
       the number of characters on that line, which you can
       return to the caller.  If not, add sizeof buf - 1 to count */
}
/* If count is non-zero here, the last line ended without a newline */
```

Comment: Can you explain SIZE.. Im not sure if that is a Var or a command C uses.

Comment: @MRP: `SIZE` is a convenient positive integral value, either a pre-processor macro or a magic number.  I didn't give you a full code since I am not sure if it's a homework question. :-)

Comment: Well if SIZE is a number I put in.. what I need it for wont work then since i don't know the size..

Comment: For instance in one line it could be 10 ints or 20 ints

Comment: No, let's say `SIZE` is 128.  Then, as my comment after `fgets()` says, if the string represented by `buf` doesn't contain a newline, it means your line was longer than 127 characters.  In which case, you call `fgets()` again, and increment `count` by 127.  So, the code above will read long lines without a problem, and correctly determine the number of characters in a line.

Answer (score 1):

The original question was how to get the number of characters in "each line" (given a line? or the current line?), while the answers have mostly given solutions how to determine the length of the first line in a file. One can easily apply some of them to determine length of current line (without guessing beforehand maximum length for a buffer).

However, what one often needs in practice is the **maximum length of any line** in a file. Then one can reserve a buffer and use fgets to read the file line by line and use some nice functions (strtok, strtod etc.) to parse lines. In practice, you can use any of the previous solutions to determine length of one line, and just scan through all lines and take the maximum.

An easy script that reads the file character by character:

```
    max=0; i=0;
    do 
        if ((c=fgetc(f))!= EOF && c!='\n') i++; 
        else { 
            if (i>max) max=i;
            i=0;
            }
    while (c!=EOF);
    return max;
```

Note: In practice, it would suffice to have an upperbound for the maximum length. A dirty solution would be to use the file size as an upperbound for the maximum length of lines.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. As far as I can tell, Sam's solution only gets the length of the first line of the file. I also like your dirty hack.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is the newline character in C.  In other languages, such as C#, you may use something like C#'s `Environment.EndLine` to overcome platform difficulties.

If you already know that your string is one line (let's call it line), use `strlen(line)` to get the number of characters in it.  Subtract 1 if it ends with the `'\n'`.

If the string has new line characters in it, you'll need to split it around the new line characters and then call `strlen()` on each substring.

Comment: He doesn't have a string, he has a file.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a Simple Algorithm :

**You require**

- File Stream (**FILE**),
- Line Number , which you want size of (**int**)

**Returns**

- Total Characters in given line

**Function :**

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  int getLengthOfLine(FILE* df,int Ofline){

    char cchar;
    int line=1;
    int  total =1;
    int  atLine=0;
    int  afterLine=0;


    while ((cchar=fgetc(df))!=EOF)
    {
      if (feof(df)){
          break ;
        }

      if (cchar == '\n' || cchar == '\0'){
        
          if(line==Ofline){
             // printf(" before %d ",total);
              atLine = total;
          }

          if(line==(Ofline+1)){
             // printf(" after %d ",total);
              afterLine = total-atLine;
          }
            
         // printf(" line is %d ",line);
           line++;
      }

      total++;
    }

    fseek(df, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    if(afterLine==0){
      return (total-atLine-1);
    }
    else
    {
      return (afterLine-1);
    }


  }
```

**Uses :**

```
FILE* fp = fopen("path-to-file" , "r");

if(fp!=NULL){
    printf(" %d",getLengthOfLine(fp,5));
}
```