# How do I find the index of a character within a string in C?

Tags: c, indexing, strchr

Suppose I have a string `"qwerty"` and I wish to find the index position of the `e` character in it. (In this case the index would be `2`)

How do I do it in C?

I found the `strchr` function but it returns a pointer to a character and not the index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String.indexOf function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824/string-indexof-function-in-c)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Just subtract the string address from what strchr returns:

```
char *string = "qwerty";
char *e;
int index;

e = strchr(string, 'e');
index = (int)(e - string);
```

Note that the result is zero based, so in above example it will be 2.

Comment: This is "right" but theoretically scary in that there's nothing in the standard stopping the length of a string from vastly exceeding the capacity of a plain 'int'. If you can depend on C99, use uintptr_t (defined in stdint.h) for this. It should also eliminate the need for that cast.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However I thought at least for a beginner example an int would be much clearer, and I am certain that the OP is not dealing with 5 GB strings.

Comment: `size_t` is probably the clearest one to use, since it's big enough to hold the length of any object (and thus any string).  The *real* issue with this code is that you should have `if (e) { } else { }` to handle the case when the character is not found within the string.

Comment: @wj32: Just for beginners it is important to learn to use the correct types. Most of the times (99%, I guess) `int` is wrong, and all these *beginner* examples just teach them the wrong attitude.

Comment: This solution helps me but as per my findings, in strchr(string, 'e') , 'e' should be in double quotes ("e") , otherwise it throws compile time error. +1 for solution.

Comment: as a newbie i would like to ask , what does (int) in  index = (int)(e - string);?

Comment: @iLearner: it is very interesting why your implementation of strchr demands char* as the second parameter. What `C` compiler do you use?

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `strcspn(string, "e")` but this may be much slower since it's able to handle searching for multiple possible characters. Using `strchr` and subtracting the pointer is the best way.

Answer (score 5):

```
void myFunc(char* str, char c)
{
    char* ptr;
    int index;

    ptr = strchr(str, c);
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Character not found\n");
        return;
    }

    index = ptr - str;

    printf("The index is %d\n", index);
    ASSERT(str[index] == c);  // Verify that the character at index is the one we want.
}
```

This code is currently untested, but it demonstrates the proper concept.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
//Returns the index of the first occurence of char c in char* string. If not found -1 is returned.
int get_index(char* string, char c) {
    char *e = strchr(string, c);
    if (e == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    return (int)(e - string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
char *string = "qwerty";
char *e = string;
int idx = 0;
while (*e++ != 'e') idx++;
```

copying to e to preserve the original string, I suppose if you don't care you could just operate over *string