# search for char sequences in C within a loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops, search

I am trying to find the most efficient way to find tags in a given char array. These "tags" are a sequence of chars located randomly within a char array.

Here is an example: given a char array: `{'a','s','s','1','m','s','g','e','x','x','r','s','1',...}`. the tag `"ss1"` indicates the beginning of a message which contains every char until a sequence of `"exx"` is found, which a tag for the end of the message, and it keeps searching the array for the next sequence of "s1". In this example, the message here is "msg".

my initial design was (pseudo code)

```
while(array[i] != '\0')
    if(array[i] == 's' && array[i+1] == 's' && array[i+2] == '1'  )
        int j = i+3;
            if(array[j] != '\0' && array[j] == 'e' && array[j+1] == 'x' && array[j+2] == 'x' )
                i += 3;
            else
                print(array[j]);
    else i++; //next char
```

may be a little flawed, but you get the idea. Is there a better way? i thought about strstr but since I'm dealing with a char array here and still looping even after deciphering a message, I thought it might be difficult to implement.

Comment: can tags be nested ? something like this is acceptable ? <ss1>msg_start_.....<ss1>innerloopmessage...<exx>msg_eng_....<exx>

Comment: no @RaviSankarRaju

Comment: Well for starters, you're indexing past the end of the array.  What if there's a single character left?  So `array[i]` is `'x'` for instance, and `array[i+1]` is `'\0'`.  So you check to see if `array[i]` is `'\0'`, which it isn't.  You then proceed to examine *three* entries, when you only know that one is available.  That is probably an access violation.  It will *probably* work, but it is not guaranteed, and it is very sloppy coding.  Never, ever try to read past the end of an array.  Even worse, you then go even further with `j`.

Comment: thanks for the catch @TomKarzes I intend to safeguard against those kind of access, I just wanted to show what i was thinking of designing and am looking for a better solution

Comment: did you try indexOf? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824/string-indexof-function-in-c

Comment: Here's a much better way to do this:  Calculate the length before starting your search, and then after that just use the length without having to check for `'\0'`.  That will be more efficient as well.  For instance, you can immediately check if `i + 2` is less than `length`, without having to scan ahead for `'\0'`.

Comment: @Proxytype strcspn is more like String.IndexOfAny() and does not mimic indexOf() like java does, wouldn't that be risky?

Comment: you can use indexOf, strstr, strchr  you named it,

Comment: @Proxytype so how will that work for the "ss%d" tag? where an int is appended to the ss indicating message number?

Comment: Better to use `strncmp` instead of `array[i+1] == 's' && array[i+2] == '1'`

Comment: indexof will tell you the first char that been found check if the second char is also "s" and next char is number...

Comment: @Proxytype better yet I can do an indexof  "ss" and check if the next is a number. I can do that right?

Comment: yeap, you can do it...

Comment: It looks like you need `strstr()` instead. If you are 100% positive there will not be embedded `'\0'`s in the array then you could add one at the end and use `strstr()` to parse the "*string*".

Comment: Can the message inside the tag may have more than three characters ?

Comment: `Is there a better way? ` Construct a state machine.

Comment: @Nishant yes it can

Comment: @i_use_the_internet Take a look at my answer. Ask me if you need any clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to maintain a state denoting how much of the tag start and end you have found. Something like this: (This code will work even if the message within the tag is of arbitrary length)

```
int state = 0;
int found = 0;
int i = 0,j;
int msgStartIndex;
int msgEndIndex;
while(array[i]){
    if((array[i] == 's' && state == 0) || (array[i] == 's' && state == 1) || (array[i] == '1' && state == 2) ){
        state++;
        if(!found && state == 3){
            msgStartIndex = i+1;
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    else if(!found && (array[i] = 's' && state == 2))
        state = 2;
    else if(!found)
        state = 0;
    if((array[i] == 'e' && state == 3) || (array[i] == 'x' && state == 2) || (array[i] == 'x' && state == 1) ){
        state--;
        if(found && state == 0){
            found = 0;
            msgEndIndex = i-3;
            for(j=msgStartIndex; j < msgEndIndex+1; j++)
                printf("%c",array[j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else if(found && (array[i] == 'e') && (state == 2 || state == 1))
        state = 2;
    else if(found)
        state = 3;
    i++;
}
```

Updated answer for start tag `st1` and end tag `ex1`

```
int state = 0;
int found = 0;
int i=0,j;
int msgStartIndex;
int msgEndIndex;
while(array[i]){
    if((array[i] == 's' && state == 0) || (array[i] == 't' && state == 1) || (array[i] == '1' && state == 2) ){
        state++;
        if(!found && state == 3){
            msgStartIndex = i+1;
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    else if(!found && (array[i] = 's' && (state == 1 || state == 2)))
        state = 1;
    else if(!found)
        state = 0;
    if((array[i] == 'e' && state == 3) || (array[i] == 'x' && state == 2) || (array[i] == '1' && state == 1) ){
        state--;
        if(found && state == 0){
            found = 0;
            msgEndIndex = i-3;
            for(j=msgStartIndex; j < msgEndIndex+1; j++)
                printf("%c",array[j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else if(found && (array[i] == 'e') && (state == 2 || state == 1))
        state = 2;
    else if(found)
        state = 3;
    i++;
```

Comment: what happens when the closing tag is ex1? how does that affect the code?

Comment: @i_use_the_internet just change `if((array[i] == 'e' && state == 3) || (array[i] == 'x' && state == 2) || (array[i] == 'x' && state == 1) )`  to `if((array[i] == 'e' && state == 3) || (array[i] == 'x' && state == 2) || (array[i] == '1' && state == 1) )`

Comment: it causes a segmentation fault for array {'a','s','t','1','m','s','g','e','x','1','r','s','t','1','s','t','1','s','s','g','e','x','1','z'}; starting tag st1 ending tag ex1

Comment: I am out on the weekend. Will get back to you on maonday IST

Comment: @i_use_the_internet Sorry, I forgot to initialize `i`, hence the segmentation fault. Try it now. Also it seems like in the example the start tag is `st1` instead of `ss1`. You will have to change the logic if you want start tag as `st1`